# Bootstrap 4: switch between cols on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've built a standard layout with a sidebar using Bootstrap's grid system (EDIT: I'm using Bootstrap 4 but could still switch). It looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

On mobile, the red area would be above the green one. I need to be able to switch between them in a way that is more convenient than scrolling, for example a switch button:

[image]

Also note the different oder of elements in the green area.

Is there a smart way to do this? Or do I have to alter the dom with JavaScript? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can bring in sidebar with a push toggle/offcanvas  in case of mobile.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: Do you still want both to visible when they're switched? Or, one is hidden and the other is shown?

Comment: @ZimSystem only one should be shown in "fullscreen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to toggle one of the BS4 flexbox utility classes. For example, apply the `flex-last` on the first (`col-md-3`) column.

To **switch the order** on mobile using a button, toggle the `flex-last` class...

```
$('#btnToggle').click(function(){
    $('.col-md-3').toggleClass('flex-last');
})
```

***EDIT:*** To show only **one at a time** (switch the visibility of the 2 divs using a button) toggle the `hidden-sm-down` class instead...

```
$('#btnToggle').click(function(){
    $('.col-md-3, .col-md-9').toggleClass('hidden-sm-down');
})
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/RVeBSPVCZI)

---

In Bootstrap 4, column order can be toggled using **CSS only**, but this switches the cols based on screen width, and therefore is not triggered by the button.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 flex-last flex-md-unordered">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

As of Bootstrap 4 Beta 3, the [ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) are named `order-*`, such as `order-1`, `order-md-2`, etc..

Comment: okay, this approach is really simple... it's not completely responsive, only the button is hidden. so i still need to use js to make it work, https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit looks promising

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, "it's not completely responsive, only the button is hidden". And yes, you need to use JS for the toggling of divs.

Comment: by responsive i mean that it behaves correctly when the window is resized. in your demo i can make the window small, hide one of the cols, make the window large again and the col is still hidden. this breaks the layout... i suppose this only works by listening to window resize events.

Comment: Try my last update. They're both visible on larger widths.

Comment: Why use javascript for something that doesn't need it?

Comment: Because the OP wants to toggle visibility on mobile "using a button", not order.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox, which means you could utilise the *order* in which things are displayed.

As usual, you can specify how it's displayed on different viewports using classes like `order-last` and `order-sm-unordered`.

[flexbox/order](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order) documentation